# Excel how to find all rows matching elements from a comma-separated list without VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

Here is my problem, I have a table with two columns: product references and corresponding notice ids:

```
 | A       | B      | C      | D      |
---------------------------------------
1| Product | Notice |        |        |
2| p1      | n1     |        |        |
3| p2      | n2     |        |        |
4| p3      | n3     |        |        |
5|         |        |        |        |
6|         |        | p1, p3 | =...   |
```

(**edit:** in my real life application, columns 'product references' and 'notice ids' are not alongside but separated by other columns)

In another cell (e.g. C6), I have a comma separated list of product references, let's say `p1, p3` and I need a formula to output the corresponding notice ids, i.e. `n1, n3` in this case, in cell D6.

**Important:** For different reasons, I **cannot use VBA**, I need a standard excel array formula.

Here is what I can do at the moment:

1. with the `FILTERXML` function, I can split the comma-separated list into an array: `FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(C6, ", ", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s")`
2. with the `TEXTJOIN` function, I can merge an array into a string.
3. I can extract a single match with a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions, e.g.:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("p3"; A:A; 0)); "not found"; INDEX(B:B; MATCH("p3"; A:A; 0)))
```

(which is not useful for me, since again the references in column A are unique)

(By the way, I don't know if there is a better way to handle error raised by `MATCH` when no match is found)

4. I can extract and join elements of column B corresponding to multiple matches to a **single reference** in column A with (array formula activated with Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
{=TEXTJOIN(", "; TRUE; IF(A:A="p2"; B:B; ""))}
```

(which is not useful for me, since again the references in column A are unique)

**In summary:** I can find and merge multiple matches to a single reference, but I cannot find and merge single unique match to multiple references (what I want to do).

---

### Failed attempts

I tried to mix the previous formulae in different ways to get what I want, but all failed with an error.

- Combining 1, 2 and 4 (using `OR` on boolean array of matches):

```
{=TEXTJOIN(", "; TRUE; IF(OR(A:A=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(C6, ", ", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s")); B:B; ""))}
```

or (using `SUM` on boolean array of matches):

```
{=TEXTJOIN(", "; TRUE; IF(SUM(A:A=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(C6, ", ", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s")); B:B; ""))}
```

Here, I am not sure how to handle the different arrays that are considered in the `IF` (column A and list of references given by `FILTERXML`).

- Combining 1, 2 and 3:

```
{=TEXTJOIN(", "; TRUE; INDEX(B:B; MATCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(C6, ", ", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s"); A:A; 0)))}
```

Here, I am not sure how to handle (i) again the different arrays that are considered (column A and list of references given by `FILTERXML`), (ii) the error raised by `MATCH` when no match is found, (iii) the array references passed to `INDEX` function.

Answer (score 3):

Nice question. If you just have Excel 2019, you could maybe go with:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(D1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),A:B,2,FALSE),""))
```

If you have Excel O365, then maybe:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,XLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(D1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),A:A,B:B,"",0))
```

Comment: Thanks! I have Excel 2016, is that an issue ? And I have another problem, in the real file, the column A and B are not side by side so I am not sure that I can use `VLOOKUP`, am I right ?

Comment: @Odin, you'd need access to `TEXTJOIN` which by the looks of your question you did have. Isn't that you have Excel 2019 then? Btw, if you are set on using `INDEX` and `MATCH` you could try: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(D1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),A:A,0)),""))`

Comment: I defined a custom function reimplementing `TEXTJOIN` (https://www.get-digital-help.com/textjoin-function/) which is the only VBA that I allowed myself.

Comment: But if you have an UDF, you are essentially using VBA. What about an UDF that just does exactly what you need then?

Comment: Because I will not be maintaining this so I want strict formula (for the people that will maintain it). The `TEXTJOIN` exception is a temporary (and simple) fix until Excel version is updated and the proper `TEXTJOIN` function is available.

Comment: Well I'd define my own UDF in your case to make this work elegantly. You now have the answer for when Textjlin comes available?

Comment: I don't know. Anyway, I totally understand your point, but the whole VBA/not VBA is not up to me so I am trying to find a solution (if not impossible) with the constraints that were given to me.

Comment: The solution with `INDEX` and `MATCH` did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(C6,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),tblProd[[Product]:[Notice]],COLUMNS(tblProd[[Product]:[Notice]]),FALSE))
```

I used tables and structured references, although you can change this to regular addressing if you absolutely need to, but I think with Tables, and auto-adjusting references, it will be easier to maintain.

Since you did not know the distance between the `Product` column and the `Notice` column, I constructed an array, and obtained the `Column Number` argument for `VLOOKUP` using the `COLUMNS` function

[image]

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use ? I am not able to replicate this. I have read that VLOOKUP cannot manage array lookup values, maybe it is a problem of Excel version. Thanks

Comment: @Odin What problem do you have with this? I'm not aware of that `VLOOKUP` limitation in Excel 2016.