# Excel vlookup keeps showing the subset option of a range

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

My reference range consists of specific diagnosis codes which are inconsistent in length (E.g. F20, F23, F201, F2031)

My reference cell for each customer consists of a list of codes delimited by commas. (E.g. A21,F23,F203)

I want to identify customers with  specific codes but face issues. Have tried vlookup, index match (e.g. F203 or F204 are not desired codes but keeps showing up as F20)

I have tried to split the reference cell into an array in vba then attempted a vlookup loop but am not pro enough to get through it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, you have a range with codes and each customer has a cell with a comma-separated list of codes.  And you want the range of codes to have a comma-separated list of customers that have that code?

Comment: Maybe this fits your use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63557745/excel-how-to-find-all-rows-matching-elements-from-a-comma-separated-list-without

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.